# ext js apply listener to componenet conditionally

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have been given an EXT JS application which contains a `datefield` that is inside a function (the function also renders other components). At the moment the function is being called twice to create (from a functional perspective) two idenctical `datefield` components. What separates the two datefield components is that the ID and name are different because they are named depending on the parameter passed into the function.

I want to give the two `datefield` components slightly differently behaviour without resorting to creating two distinct `datefield` components. I was wondering whether it is possible to only apply a listener to a component if some condition is satisfied?

EG:

```
if(some condition is true){
    select: function(datefield, date){
               //code
        }
}
```

Or whether I would have to give both components all the listeners but perform the conditional inside, so that if the condition is not satisfied then that event is never fired for that component.

EG:

```
select: function(datefield, date){
    if(some condition is true){
        //code             
    }
    else{
       //Do nothing as this component doesn't need this listener.
}
}
```

I am fairly sure the second way would work but I'm not sure it's a good idea. The first way seems slightly cleaner; I'm not sure it looks too good to have empty else bodies lying around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `on` method of your datefield.

```
if(some condition){
    datefield.on('select', function(field,value){
        // code for your select here.
    });
}
```

I think this should do what you need.

Comment: So when you use the `on` method, can the handler function use the same parameters as the event listener? For example for a select event listener in a `datefield` the function parameters are the `datefield` itself and the selected date.

Comment: You can use like this `datefield.on('select', onDateSelect)` and then have: `onDateSelect: function(field, value) {}`

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar implementation on other components, basically something like:

```
 var yourComponent = Ext.create('...',{});

 if (something is true){
    yourComponent.on('select', this._doStuff, yourComponent);  
 }

//
 _doStuff: function(component){
   //do stuff
 }
```

Hope this helps.